# In my Unity C# game a gameobject is supposed to get thrown but it does absolutely nothing - what's the problem?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on an Unity project in C# and my rigidbody isn't moving but I don't get an error. It should get thrown forward and upward but it does nothing - what am I doing wrong here?

Or can it be that my code isn't the problem but I messed something up unn unity?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ThrowObject;
    public Canvas StartMenuC, m_SettingsC, m_ShopC;
    public Button m_Start, m_Settings, m_Shop, m_CloseShop;
    public RawImage m_SettingsImage, m_RTXON, m_RTXOFF;
    public Texture m_Texture, m_Texture2;
    public Toggle m_RTX;
    public Text MoneyText;
    string m_ForceXString = string.Empty;
    string m_ForceYString = string.Empty;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform Forward, Upward;
    private Vector3 m_StartPos, m_StartForce;
    private Vector3 m_NewForce;

    float m_ForceX, m_ForceY;

    private int Money = 100;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       // rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        m_NewForce = new Vector3(-5.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        m_ForceX = 10;
        m_ForceY = 10;

        m_ForceXString = "0";
        m_ForceYString = "0";

        m_StartPos = transform.position;
        m_StartForce = rb.transform.position;
        m_NewForce = new Vector3(m_ForceX, m_ForceY, 0);

        MoneyText = GetComponent<Text>();

        m_CloseShop.onClick.AddListener(CloseShop);
        m_Settings.onClick.AddListener(Settings);
        m_Start.onClick.AddListener(StartGame);
        m_Shop.onClick.AddListener(ShopOpen);

        m_SettingsImage = GetComponent<RawImage>();

        m_SettingsC.enabled = false;
        m_ShopC.enabled = false;

        m_RTX.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {
            CheckToggleOn(m_RTX);
        });

        // PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Money", Money);

        //     MoneyText.text = "Money:  " + Money.ToString() + " $";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }

    void Settings()
    {
        if (m_SettingsC.enabled == false)
        {
            m_SettingsC.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            m_SettingsC.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void ShopOpen()
    {
        m_ShopC.enabled = true;
    }

    void CloseShop()
    {
        m_ShopC.enabled = false;
    }

    private void CheckToggleOn(Toggle change)
    {
        if (m_RTX.isOn)
        {
            m_RTXOFF.enabled = false;
            m_RTXON.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            m_RTXON.enabled = false;
            m_RTXOFF.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void StartGame()
    {
        m_SettingsC.enabled = false;
        StartMenuC.enabled = false;
        m_ShopC.enabled = false;

        Instantiate(ThrowObject, new Vector3(0, 356, 26), Quaternion.identity);

        Debug.Log("HelloWorld");

        if (ThrowObject)
        {
            Debug.Log("Throw object = true");

            rb.AddForce(m_NewForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

What is my error?

And bc of: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." and I don't know what else I am supposed to write here I'll tell what the game should look like when done it will be a 3D Mobile Game where you have the objective to throw stuff out of the window I know it's idiotic but its based on a true story from my old school where someone often threw schoolbags out of the window and had to get them back and the school was in the 5. floor

Comment: When exactly do you call startgame? As thats the only time you apply any force

Comment: @BugFinder it's in `m_Start.onClick.AddListener(StartGame);` but yeah .. @OP please debug your code and tell us if the according line is even reached or not

Comment: it is i debuged it 5 times to see if i miss sth but no everything is reached

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you want to add force to your newly instantiated "ThrowObject", correct?
However, instead of referencing this object, you add force to "rb", which seemingly is not at all connected to the new object.

Instead, you might want to do something like this:

```
rb = Instantiate(ThrowObject, new Vector3(0, 356, 26), Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```